# Does using Scala implicit classes feature on Spark Dataframe is a monkey patching?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, implicit

I'm trying to add side-effect functionality to Spark DataFrame by expanding DataFrame class using Scala implicit classes feature for the reason that  "Dataset Transform Method" only allows returning DataFrame.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) - "The term monkey patch ... referred to changing code sneakily – and possibly incompatibly with other such patches – at runtime"

In this [post](https://mungingdata.com/apache-spark/chaining-custom-dataframe-transformations/) the writer warns from "Monkey Patching with Implicit Classes", but I'm not sure his claims are correct because we are not
changing any classes.

Does the following example is potentially "monkey patching" and could somehow be incompatible with Spark future version, or because I'm not overwriting the current DataFrame class and just expanding, it can be no harm?

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, get_json_object}
    
  object dataFrameSql {
    implicit class DataFrameExSql(dataFrame: DataFrame) {
      def writeDFbyPartition(repartition: Int, output: String): Unit = {
        dataFrame
          .repartition(repartition)
          .write
          .option("partitionOverwriteMode", "dynamic")
          .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
          .parquet(output)
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Extension methods work at compile-time, so no this is not monkey patching is just sugar syntax.

Comment: You are just telling the compiler that whenever it sees `somedf.extractJsonCols(...)` where `somedf` is an instance of `DataFrame`, it should replace it with `DataFrameExSql(somedf).extractJsonCols(...)` before compiling it further. Spark doesn't even know that such translation occurrs. It could break though if one day Spark's `DataFrame` gains a method with the same signature, which will prevent your extension method from being called.

Comment: @HristoIliev I have edited the question and attached a post where the writer claims that Implicit Classes could be somehow Monkey Patching

Comment: Do not get confused by the free use of terminology. Monkey Patching changes the class itself in *runtime* and those changes become visible everywhere. Extension methods added via implicits are only visible to the compiler and only where the implicit classes are in scope. There is no true monkey patching in Scala (or any other compiled JVM language) since you cannot (easily) modify loaded JVM classes. In dynamic languages such as Ruby and Python, classes are just data structures and one can poke inside and change methods at will.

Comment: Extension methods add a rule to the compiler telling it to transform `obj.extMethod(...)` into `ExtClass(obj).extMethod(...)` when compiling the code. This is only syntactic sugar, not modification of the original class.